# How to prevent script execution on back/forward button press in browser?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, this may be a very old question but I didn't know how to reference it exactly since I have no idea what's going on in the first place. I noticed that a lot of forums use this very subtle feature, which limits some script functionality unless the page is refreshed or navigated to the "legit" way. For instance, if you click on someone's post the topic's views count will increment but NEVER if you page back and forward again. In my case the script does the same thing every time and my increment function works no matter what. How is it done? Caching? Buffering? Cookies? I've tried caching but that would simply make the pages static. What is the most common way to achieve this?

Just in case, here is my topic view increment function, though I doubt it's of any use here:

```
function incr_view($conn, $topic_id) {
    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE topics SET views = views + 1 WHERE id='$topic_id'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be implemented in various ways. For example, you can use sessions:

```
session_start();
if (array_key_exists("is_voted", $_SESSION) && $_SESSION["is_voted"]) {
   echo "Already voted.";
   exit();
}

/* Put the main code here */

$_SESSION["is_voted"] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_SESSION (and mostly all the forum you know, they use SESSION, too).
Here is my method:

```
isset($_SESSION["viewed"]){ // Check if the viewed initalized
     if (!in_array($topic_id, $_SESSION["viewed"])){
        incr_view($conn, $topic_id); // run your function
        $_SESSION['viewed'] = array_push($_SESSION['viewed'], $topic_id); // add to session to determine that this user visited this topic already
     }else{
        // already viewed, do nothing
     }
}else{   // Create if not, insert topic_id also
     $_SESSION["viewd"] = [$topic_id];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, guys! This works but it's not exactly what I was looking for. With this the increment will not work even on refresh, which is to be expected, of course, since the condition will prevent it from happening altogether, but the forums I'm talking about don't restrict it like that. Like I said, if you re-navigate to the same topic using links or page refresh the counter works again. I doubt they overflow $_SESSION with all those IDs.